# Create a nested json object from another nested json object [HOLD]

Tags: javascript, json

As the question states, I want to create a new object from a current json object.

My current json object:

```
{
  "name": "Parent",
  "children": [
      {
          "name": "Child1",
          "children": [
              {
                  "name": "GrandChid1",
                  "children": []
              },
              {
                  "name": "GrandChild2",
                  "children": []
              },
              {
                  "name": "GrandChild3",
                  "children": [
                      {
                          "name": "GrandGrandChild1",
                          "children": [
                              {
                                  "name": "GrandGrandGrandChild1",
                                  "children": []
                              },
                              {
                                  "name": "GrandGrandGrandChild2",
                                  "children": []
                              }
                          ]
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ]
      }
  ]
}
```

Now the new object will look something like this:

```
{
  "Parent": [
      {
          "Child1": [
              {
                  "GrandChid1": ''
              },
              {
                  "GrandChild2": ''
              },
              {
                  "GrandChild3": [
                      {
                          "GrandGrandChild1": [
                              {
                                  "GrandGrandGrandChild1": ''
                              },
                              {
                                  "GrandGrandGrandChild2": ''
                              }
                          ]
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ]
      }
  ]
}
```

If there are no children then it becomes a string (simple key value) pair.
Any help is appreciated especially with a recursive solution.

Comment: FYI, SO is not for **I want to**. Its for *I'm stuck here*.

Comment: @HassanAbbas does first child of 'Parent' should be `Child1`: [...] instad of {'name':'Child1', children:[...]} in yur desired output json ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, its a mistake on my end. I will edit :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
let r = o=> (o.children=o.children.map(x=>r(x)),
             {[o.name]: o.children.length ? o.children:''});
```

```js
let c= {
  "name": "Parent",
  "children": [
      {
          "name": "Child1",
          "children": [
              {
                  "name": "GrandChid1",
                  "children": []
              },
              {
                  "name": "GrandChild2",
                  "children": []
              },
              {
                  "name": "GrandChild3",
                  "children": [
                      {
                          "name": "GrandGrandChild1",
                          "children": [
                              {
                                  "name": "GrandGrandGrandChild1",
                                  "children": []
                              },
                              {
                                  "name": "GrandGrandGrandChild2",
                                  "children": []
                              }
                          ]
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ]
      }
  ]
}

let r = o=> (o.children=o.children.map(x=>r(x)),{[o.name]: o.children.length ? o.children:''});

console.log(r(c));
```